# Magento 2.3 Punchout Gateway integration issue. Product Price is showing 0 on detail and cart pages

Tags: magento2

I am facing a strange issue, Our site is integrated with Punchout Gateway. While simulating the site using cXML the product price turns into 0 on the detail page as well as in cart page.
The website is working fine individually. Can you please help me with that.
[image: The issue]

Answer (score 0):

You should check the account you're logged in as. It probably doesn't belong to the correct customer group or company in your eCommerce environment.